# Windows 10 becomes unresponsive when I turn my monitor on

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, mini-displayport

**The Hardware:**

- AMD Ryzen 3950x
- 64GB DDR4 Memory
- MSI Geforce GTX AERO 1080 TI
- Crosshair VIII Hero Motherboard

**The issue:**

I run a quad monitor setup - 3 1080p monitors connected via Display Port to HDMI or HDMI proper and a fourth 4k monitor (running at 4k resolution) connected via Display port to Display port mini. The issue is that the 4k monitor is treated as a device; when it is turned on the operating system (Windows 10 Pro) detects a new monitor and reconfigures the entire display environment. All of my windows are repositioned to different monitors, and the task bar becomes unresponsive for up to seven to ten minutes after. When I turn it off, similar behavior happens and the system is again unresponsive for up to ten minutes. I feel like this is a malfunction of some kind, there's no way this level of hardware should be misbehaving this badly. How do I prevent this?

I've tried disabling DDC/CI on all four monitors, no luck.

Comment: The re-arranging is normal. The unresponsiveness is not. Windows stores the arrangement of monitors based on the entire set of monitors currently connected (which means turned on as well). Add one monitor or take away one monitor... and Windows sees it as a completely new set. This is because monitors are not "dumb devices" any more like they were in the 90's. With each successive improvement in connection standard, monitors and computers have gotten more and more interconnected. With HDMI and DisplayPort  a monitor really is another device from the OS's perspective... like a mouse or printer.

Comment: Any idea what I can do to debug the unresponsiveness?

Comment: I was having a similar problem a few days ago, which was Windows becoming unresponsive when I wakeup my laptop and connect external monitor (I do these 2 things at the same time). The solution that helped me was to disable hybrid sleep.